# Как установить Xhprof, если его не устраивает версия php5-common?

Tags: php, debian, профилирование

Захотел заняться профилированием кода. Выбрал Xhprof т.к. до этого с ним работал, но проблема с установкой возникла.

```
aptitude install php5-xhprof

The following NEW packages will be installed:
  php5-xhprof{b}
0 packages upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 494 not upgraded.
Need to get 13.6 kB of archives. After unpacking 74.8 kB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php5-xhprof : Depends: php5-common (= 5.5.25-1~dotdeb+7.1) but 5.5.24-1~dotdeb+wheezy.1 is installed and it is kept back.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     php5-xhprof [Not Installed]
```

Вывод **dpkg -l|grep php**, если кому надо.

```
rc  php5-cgi                             5.4.34-0+deb7u1               amd64        server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (CGI binary)
ii  php5-cli                             5.5.24-1~dotdeb+wheezy.1      amd64        command-line interpreter for the php5 scripting language
ii  php5-common                          5.5.24-1~dotdeb+wheezy.1      amd64        Common files for packages built from the php5 source
ii  php5-curl                            5.5.24-1~dotdeb+wheezy.1      amd64        CURL module for php5
ii  php5-fpm                             5.5.24-1~dotdeb+wheezy.1      amd64        server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (FPM-CGI binary)
ii  php5-gd                              5.5.24-1~dotdeb+wheezy.1      amd64        GD module for php5
ii  php5-imagick                         5.5.24-1~dotdeb+wheezy.1      amd64        imagick module for php5
ii  php5-memcache                        5.5.24-1~dotdeb+wheezy.1      amd64        memcache module for php5
ii  php5-mysqlnd                         5.5.24-1~dotdeb+wheezy.1      amd64        MySQL module for php5 (Native Driver)
ii  php5-readline                        5.5.24-1~dotdeb+wheezy.1      amd64        Readline module for php5
```

Ему не нравится php5-common своей версией, при попытке обновить php5-common, он хочет всё к хренам обновить/удалить, как-то жирно для [пакета устанавливающего документацию и примеры для php5](https://packages.debian.org/ru/sid/php5-common). Хотел собрать xhprof из исходников, для этого ему нужен phpize, а для него php5-dev, а он хочет удалить за сотню пакетов. Может где-нибудь можно нарыть xhprof который встанет на 5.5.24? Основная проблема в том, что **сервак боевой** и это заставляет стрематься любого возможного падения. Буду рад идеям и советам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

судя по именам пакетов (встречается "dotdeb") у вас подключен репозиторий от dotdeb.org.

насколько я вижу, пакеты `php.*5.5.24.*` уже «ушли» в [архив](http://archives.dotdeb.org/dists/wheezy/php5/5.5.24/binary-amd64/), и при попытке установки `php5-dev` из основного репозитория предлагается обновить все эти пакеты до присутствующей ныне в этом репозитории версии `5.5.25`.

к сожалению, в их архиве нет требующегося вам пакета `php5-xhprof`, поэтому придётся собирать его самостоятельно, установив `php5-dev` из архива dotdeb.

проще всего, вероятно, [скачать файл нужной архитектуры](http://archives.dotdeb.org/dists/wheezy/php5/5.5.24/) и установить пакет вручную:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i php5-dev_5.5.24-1~dotdeb+wheezy.1_*.deb
```

вот [тут](https://www.dotdeb.org/2008/09/25/how-to-package-php-extensions-by-yourself/) Guillaume Plessis на примере `fileinfo` объясняет, как собрать пакет, содержащий [pecl](http://pecl.php.net/)-расширение. попробуйте применить инструкции для требующегося вам [xhprof](http://pecl.php.net/package/xhprof).

Comment: Спасибо большое, похоже будто всё получится.

Comment: Да, конечно. Пока руки не дошли проверить, только глазами пробежался.

Comment: Спасибо, всё работает!